# How to make git prefer tab completion of filename instead of branch name?

Tags: linux, git, shell

If there is a filename and a branch name with a common prefix, then pressing tab in the shell, as part of a git command, will autocomplete the branch name. Is there a way to make it use the filename instead?

Comment: It is possible that hacking the /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt (which on ubuntu points to /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt ) can do this. But it is 100s of lines long, and I ran away screaming.   It'd be nice if we got both filenames and branches together, I think.

Comment: Vote to reopen as it is about "software tools primarily used by programmers."

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of most Git commands is:

```
git command branch -- file
```

So, to force filename completion:

```
git command -- ⇥
```

(that's the tab key)

---

This can even be used to resolve ambiguities:

```
git checkout docs --
```

switches to branch `docs`; whereas:

```
git checkout -- docs
```

overwrites the file/directory `docs` with the contents from the index